# React Login Button Takes User new Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to learn to react front end by creating a simple frontend website. My goal is simple I want to implement a login menu when I run the app. The user will log in through this window and if the user is a regular user it will redirect the user to a new component call regular.js. If the user is admin then redirect the user to another page lets calls that admin.js. I have been trying to understand how to redirect in react. Like in javascript I can write if Credentials match then go to this page can I do that too in react? However, I do not want the user to log out automatically when the redirect happens. I am not sure how to approach it because I read other answers saying use hooks but then some said use routes as well. I am providing the App.js, index.js, and loginForm.js file underneath, any direction will be helpful or documents to refer to like guide me to do this will be helpful. I am not looking for a design or any content on the new pages I just want the redirect to work while the user is logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not handle login on the front end with React states, there is 0 security in this. You should look into how to implement authentication, consider reading through some tutorials like this one: https://bezkoder.com/react-express-authentication-jwt/